# Indentationerror: unexpected indent python

Tags: python

I looked up the reasons for indent error, ie four spaces instead of tab and tried deleting all the spaces and replacing them myself with 4 spaces to no avail.

The error comes on line 2. With the arrow under the p of print.

```
filepath = "F:\marketing II\programming\python\projects\testpic.jpg"
    print ("Uploading " + filepath)
    insta = InstagramSession()
    if insta.login(user, pass):
        media_id = insta.upload_photo("/tmp/small.jpg")
        print media_id
        if media_id is not None:
            insta.configure_photo(media_id, "")
```

Comment: Why is everything after the first line indented?

Comment: Ah there we go thanks. I copied it from a readme file and I guess it was written wrong in there. (still new to this)

Comment: This is why you don't copy and paste code. ALWAYS rewrite it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the indent, it should look like this:

```
filepath = "F:\marketing II\programming\python\projects\testpic.jpg"
print ("Uploading " + filepath)
insta = new InstagramSession()
if insta.login(user, pass):
    media_id = insta.upload_photo("/tmp/small.jpg")
    print media_id
    if media_id is not None:
        insta.configure_photo(media_id, "")
```

Yse indents only after instructions like loops, if statements, while expression. This is because in python you cond use curly bracets, but indents. You can find more info about indentions [here](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk).

**Update**:

Also you are using a class InstagramSession, so you need to place a keyword new before it.

Comment: Ok I got past that bit but now I have a message saying instagram session is not defined form line: insta = InstagramSession()

So what am I supposed to put there to make it work?

Comment: You need to add new keyword before it, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

you do not need to indent in that line. your code should look like this:

```
filepath = "F:\marketing II\programming\python\projects\testpic.jpg"
print ("Uploading " + filepath)
insta = InstagramSession()
if insta.login(user, pass):
    media_id = insta.upload_photo("/tmp/small.jpg")
    print media_id
    if media_id is not None:
        insta.configure_photo(media_id, "")
```

Comment: Yes I copied and pasted from a file which was wrong I suppose. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, indentation marks code blocks. They start under a line that ends with a colon `:`, and they end when the indentation ends. Since your first line which assigns the variable `filepath` does not start a block, you must not indent further below it. Either adjust your indentation or insert a line that does open a block, such as `if True:`.